# Unable to install a Nuget Package in a .NET Framework 4.7.2 project

Tags: c#, wpf, nuget-package

In my `WPF` project using `.NET Framework 4.7.2` in `VS2017`, I'm trying to install [Interop.MSUtil.dll](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Interop.MSUtil.dll/) NuGet package as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49696629/1232087). I do need this package installed, so could someone please help me installing it or providing a workaround.

**Error**:

> > Install-Package : Could not install package 'Interop.MSUtil.dll 1.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2', 
> >     but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
> >     At line:1 char:1
> >     + Install-Package Interop.MSUtil.dll -Version 1.0.0
> >     + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> >         + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
> >         + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Comment: The error is self explanatory, the nuget doesn't support 4.7.2, now usually you would go to the nuget site and it would tell you what it does support, but the authors neglected to add this information, nor does it look like there is a project site. In this case, there is nothing we can do to help you, i would consider contacting them or reading the documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the NuGet package for Interop.MSUtil.dll is not compatible with the `.NET 4.7.2 Framework`.

However, if you have LogParser installed on your machine and you have administrator access, you can recreate it locally.

1. Locate your copy of LogParser.  The most likely place is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Log Parser 2.2`.
2. Locate your [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs).  In Windows 10, just type `developer command prompt` into the Windows search bar.
3. Run it as Administrator.  Generally this can be done by right-clicking on the Developer Command Prompt item for the context menu.
4. `cd` to the location where LogParser is installed.
5. Run the following command:

   `tlbimp LogParser.dll /out:Interop.MSUtil.dll`

This should build a new version of `Interop.MSUtil.dll` which will be friendly to your version of the Framework.

Now you can add it as a reference manually by browsing to the LogParser directory and selecting the new DLL.

Don't forget you may need to set `Embed Interop Types` to `False`.

Note that this draws heavily from [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11203698/3059082).

Answer (score 0):

If Nuget package is not declared to be installed it can't be installed through the package manager.

However you can install a .dll file. First install it on the some project where it can be installed. Then in packages folder of the project find some .dll file that you find appropriate. Finally add it as the reference to the project. It may or may not work depending on the package itself but that is the only way if it has any chance to work.